# Overlapping fragments when changing tabs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I am having a problem with my fragments overlapping each other. I have an Android ActionBar tab and I am using `ActionBarSherlock`. When I select other tabs the fragment from the `ListFragment` is placed on top of my `HomeFragment`. It is like it is not getting detached properly.

Below is the code for `HomeFragment`:

```
public class HomeFragment extends SherlockFragment
                          implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private View homeView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homefragment, container, false);
        return homeView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, this,"apple");
        ft.attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

}
```

Code for `HerbFragment`:

```
public class HerbsFragment extends SherlockListFragment 
                           implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
    String apple_versions[] = new String[]{
            "Pancreas",
            "Blood"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                                                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            apple_versions);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, this,"apple");
        ft.attach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.detach(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code in your HerbFragment is missplaced because you should handle the tab stuff in the activity/fragment that has the tabs, not in the tabs. You can handle that in your HomeFragment in two different ways:

-When the user clicks in a tab, replace the current fragment: just change this for a `ft.replace` (and delete the `ft.attach` line):

```
ft.add(android.R.id.content, this,"apple");
ft.attach(this);
```

-Attach the new fragment and detach the previous: just get a reference from the attached fragment if you know which it is and detach it in the same method you're attaching the new one.